# How to disable a widget tree in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen (in Flutter), containing several child widgets (buttons, textfields etc.).

When the user is tapping a certain button, there's a **lengthy async call**.
During this call I'd like to **disable the entire screen and its child widgets**.
Plus, I'd like the user to "see" that the widgets are disabled (prevent the user from interacting with the buttons, textfields etc.).

How can I do this?

P.S.
The [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) / [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widgets won't show any visible hints that the screen is disabled, so I'm looking for another solution

Comment: the bool value you set to the absorbing property on the AbsorberPointer, you can use it across your widget to inform the user that is disabled. like the ElevatedButton, you can assign something like this, onPressed: isAbsorbing ? null : yourMethod(),

Comment: See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalBarrier-class.html

Comment: @Gwhyyy but then I have to implement it for each and every intractable widget in my screen...

Comment: @RandalSchwartz this is close to what I was looking for (a global widget that prevents interaction with all its child widgets). I'm looking for something that will render the child widgets as grayed-out, but I'll look into this widget

Comment: I think it's better to have full control on the screen while disabling widgets you want to inform the user is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Im used to do it Using Provider And Visibility Widget

I add isLoading function to the provider when the user taps the button isLoading status changed to true after that I wrapped my body :Widget()//add if else here

Provider isLoading Class

```
 bool _isLoading = false;

  void setIsLOading(bool val) {
    _isLoading = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
```

this is where I add my Widget

```
   return Consumer<FileDownloader>(builder: (context, value, child) {
          return value.isLoading
              ? CircularPrgressIndicator()
              :ElevatedButton()
```

Comment: but then I have to implement it for each and every intractable widget in my screen...

Comment: no i mean, that For example in your body you have Collumn( children[ Text(),ElevatedButton() ])then you need to add value.isLoading before the collumn

Comment: i do the same with provider, you can disable the widget tree you want. eg if you have a list replacing it by a progress indicator while long running process, and the other tree eg the header of the screen will remaing unchanged if you don't need to disable or hide it